# how to display first letter of first and last name of profile user within a icon | Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, css

For eg:- my name is **hitesh rayal** 
and want to display it in the same way as they have done in the below screenshot

[image: example image]

get profile user first letter of first name and last name and display it in a icon or anything like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i did it if any body want the same can copy paste the same
samplecmp.apxc

```
public class ProfileValueController {
     @AuraEnabled
     public static String getfirstlastname()
    {
    String returnString = '' ;
    String FirstName = UserInfo.getFirstName();//Returns the context user's firstname
    System.Debug('FirstName-' + FirstName);
    String LastName = UserInfo.getLastName();//Returns the context user's last name.
    System.Debug('LastName-' + LastName);
    returnString = FirstName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1) + ' '+ 
    LastName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1);
    system.debug('returnString'+returnString);
    return returnString;
}}
```

sample.cmp

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="Fnameletter" type="String"/>  
<div class="circle">{!v.Fnameletter}</div>`
```

samplecontroller.js

```
({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.getfirstlastname");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.Fnameletter", response.getReturnValue());
      } else if (state === "ERROR") {
        var errors = response.getError();
        if (errors) {
          if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
            console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

sample.css

```
.THIS.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2a9fd8;
  /* display: inline-block;*/
}
```

Comment: code dumps are generally frowned upon - mind explaining every code block section?